# Can/should I make id column that is part of a composite key non-unique

Tags: mysql, database, datamodel

I have a hierarchical model of 3 levels. For instance, `states` have one-to-many `cities` have one-to-many `households`. A few questions:

1. A `city` can only exist as part of a `state`, so if I make a composite key for the `city`, which includes `stateId`, can I make `cityId` auto_increment, but only for a given state? In other words, use auto_increment, but allow state 1 to have city with `id = 3`, but also state 4 to have a city with `id = 3`?
2. If the above is impossible, what could be a strategy to generate unique id's for cities?
3. `households` are one level lower; should their composite key include both the `stateId`, and the `cityId`?

Comment: "A city can only exist as part of a state" - Puerto Rico would like a word....

Comment: "an I make cityId auto_increment, but only for a given state? - **no**, sorry, you can't. The reason is because databases are designed to make `INSERT` a _fast_ operation, which means an RDBMS can't scan an entire table to determine what value should be used for the next _partitioned_ `auto_increment`  value - instead the _next_ `auto_increment` value is associated with the table, or maybe even the entire database, depending on your RDBMS. It isn't just MySQL: MS SQL behaves the same with `IDENTITY` too.

Comment: "If the above is impossible, what could be a strategy to generate unique id's for cities?" - you **can** continue to use `auto_increment`, but you just need to drop your hope-or-expectation that you can have "partitioned" incrementing integers.

Comment: "households are one level lower; should their composite key include both the stateId, and the cityId?" - probably not: households move around the country or even around the world, so _if_ their PK did include `stateId` and/or `cityId` then that introduces a lot of pain from either manually repairing/editing records if a household changes the `stateId` they're in, or you'll have to resort to `ON UPDATE CASCADE` (which is just painful and ugly). The rule-of-thumb is: _don't use mutable data for keys_.

Comment: @Dai Ah, ok that's helpful. Thanks. So is there any benefit to making the stateId part of the city's PK? By the way, the example is contrived. In my scenario, the "household" cannot move around. It always exists in a particular state, in a particular city.